# Index my own data in Solr

Tags: solr, indexing

I am new to Solr and have a couple of questions to ask help from more experienced people:

1. I am able to get example running, however what is exactly the start.jar?
2. I know by running "java -jar start.jar", i can start solr. But do i run this command after i index my own data, not the given sample data? if not, what should i do to run my own solr instance with my own indexed data?
3. I do need to index my own sample data, not related to the given example solr thing at all. How exactly should i do it? Should i copy the example directory then modify the fields in sechema.xml? should i then run the post.sh accordingly to index the data like what i did to set up the example solr?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Decide what will be the document structure u store in SOLR. (Somewhat like creating the schema of a relational DB for one table).
2. remove the example core and create your own core with that schema
3. once the schema works with no errors (you check the server logs that hosts the SOLR app) You can start feed the data you have into SOLR. You POST it via HTTP in a specific structure which is documented in the SOLR Wiki. Various frameworks have some classes to handle that.

Marked as Wiki as this is too broad an answer for someone who did not bother to RTFM...

Comment: thanks a lot for your quick response! I would like to start with something really simple, a text file that contains (id, name, value) pairs on each line. Example: 1001  Title  Professor, 1001 Name Jenny, 1001 Latitude -122, 1001 Longitude 34. I will start with indexing and tokenizing the Name field. According to the steps u provided, i still have questions (please bear with me).
(1) what do you mean by removing the example core? which directory are you referring to? (2)can you please point me to the wiki where it mentions how to post data?

Answer (score 0):

Dear custom indexing is not a difficult task as I have worked on it just a few days ago. First you need to write your documnet is xml,csv or json( format supported in solr) containing fields according to your schema.xml, then run following command in example/exampledocs

For a document mydoc.xml

**./post.sh mydoc.xml**

if in output, status value is 0 then indexing is successful and you can search your document in solr

Reference:http://www.solrtutorial.com/solr-in-5-minutes.html

Answer (score 0):

Though the question is old, but I am writing for new visitors with same issue. The question can't be answered in few words. You must understand what Solr is, whats Solr Admin UI, why we need Solr instead a relational database. Then you can understand how to import sample data. I have recently published two articles i.e. Solr Introduction and Importing Sample Data, these might be helpful for you.

http://www.devtrainings.com/2017/03/apache-solr-introduction-and-server.html

http://www.devtrainings.com/2017/03/apache-solr-index-data-and-run-search.html